# Passing data from view controller to tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, pass-data

I tried to pass the data from `ViewController` to one of children of `TabBarController` with this block of code:

```
class LoginViewController: UITabBarController{

//here are the requests and after all are finished the next is
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()){

    let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    prefs.setObject("demo", forKey: "USERNAME")
    prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
    prefs.synchronize()
    print(templates[0])

    let vc = self.tabBarController!.viewControllers![0] as! HomeViewController
    vc.templateForCell = templates
```

And in the second ViewController, child of TabBarController i have this:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var templateForCell: [VQuizTemplateTo]?

@IBOutlet weak var collection: UICollectionView!

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    collection.delegate = self
    collection.dataSource = self
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TemplatesCell{

        cell.configureCell(templateForCell!)

        return cell

    } else {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}


func  collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.templateForCell!.count
}


func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSizeMake(88, 116)
   }   
}
```

I got `error (fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value)` in the `HomeViewController`.
What would I suppose to do?

Comment: numberOfRowsForSection implemented?

Comment: @Mr.UB can't find such func. i'm typing to override it, but doesn't show up

Comment: Conform to collection datasource and delegates ’class LoginViewController: UITabBarController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate’ - then this method will show up.

Comment: @Mr.UB My collection view is in HomeViewController and there i have the protocols and  func  collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int), if you that mean! I think its problem like i don't get templates on the other page in collectionView....really don't know what to do ...

Comment: `@IBOutlet` is connected?

Comment: @IBOutlet collection cell? yes...

Comment: No `IBOutlet` of `collection view` and also your code of `numberOfItemssAt...`

Comment: Everything is conncected! It runs code of HomeViewController where my collection view is, before i login into app. I don't know how it is possible...

Comment: show your code of `numberOfItemssAt...`

Comment: @Mr.UB i edited my question...there is the whole code now :)

Comment: put a breakpoint inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and see if it is executing or not.

Comment: It accually report an error on 'return self.templateForCell!.count' . Like it first run the code in HomeVC before LoginVC which is before every VC. I don't why !?

Comment: print `templateForCell` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: it prints nil !

Comment: what is the output of `print(templates[0])`?

Comment: Means that you have no data to display.

Comment: i cant get to ' templates ' because as soon as my login screen loads, the code from HomeViewController runs before every earlier code. And it should login in application first and then get templates from Alamofire, and then to run the code from HomeVC and load collection view...

Comment: Try this: `var templateForCell: [VQuizTemplateTo]? = [ ]`